# Hide section numbers, but keep numbering

Tags: sectioning, numbering

How do I hide section number in section heading ? I can't just use `\section*{xxxx}`, because I want subsections numbered correctly. I also tried :

```
\section*{xxxx}  
\stepcounter{xxxx}
```

Which hides section number and keeps subsection numbers. Unfortunately this solution also hides section in table of contents, which is undesirable.

Next attempt was :

```
\chapter{}
\section*{xxxx}
\addtocounter{section}{1}
```

However this made numbering of subsections continue on and on instead of reseting at new section.
 So what can I do to make it behave as normal, just not showing section numbers ? Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think your best bet is to redefine `\thesection`, which is the macro that normally *prints* the section number.

```
\renewcommand\thesection{}
```

If you want subsection numbers to include the section numbers that aren't getting printed, you will also need to redefine `\thesubsection`, which normally calls `\thesection`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesection{}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\@arabic\c@section.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Ok works well in hiding section number.Problem with this command is that it also hides section number in subsection numbering, which I want to keep so subsections are numbered like .1 .2 .3 and so on.

Comment: See edit - I thought of that right after I hit save :)

Comment: Don't do this; there's most likely a package for that.

Comment: This still slightly indents the section (at least when used with `scrartcl`), so I prefer answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300055/77029

Comment: Unfortunately this also has the disadvantage of not only affecting the section title, but also every occurence as a reference (`\ref`).

Comment: yes, do you have a solution that does not erase also the `\ref` @zwol ? Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou I think you had better ask a new question about that, explaining exactly what you want to see in the section heading, the table of contents, and \ref output.

Answer (score 49):

Redefining `\thesection` is not sufficient. This will do better: the section title will be aligned to the left margin and not indented; in the table of contents, the section title will appear horizontally aligned to the chapter titles.

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname #1ignore\expandafter\endcsname\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}
\let\sectionignore\@gobbletwo
\let\latex@numberline\numberline
\def\numberline#1{\if\relax#1\relax\else\latex@numberline{#1}\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Title}
\section{Xyz}
\subsection{Here we are}
\end{document}
```

[image: Contents]

---

[image: Chapter]

Comment: Unfortunately this affects not only the section title, but also erases its counting when using `\ref`? (ok admittedly referring to a section number when it is not printed is a bit weird, but still?) Thanks!

Comment: @Matifou And what should `\ref` produce if there's nothing to show? Even if we keep the numbering, how's a user supposed to find it?

Answer (score 10):

If you're using a KOMA-script document class (e.g., `scrartcl`), then for normal behaviour, just not showing section numbers, include in your preamble

```
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{}
```

This also works for `\chapterformat` (if you're using `scrbook` or `scrreport`), `\partformat`, all the way down to `\subparagraphformat`.

The counter counts the section despite the number label not being shown, so TOC, PDF bookmarks, and subsection numbering all operate as they should (tested with `hyperref` and `bookmark` packages loaded.)

Comment: @egreg's response works great, but it's a mouthful to use repeatedly.      So I tried to define a macro that I could invoke whenever  I needed this functionality.   However, when I do the obvious thing.  `\def\foo{  @egreg's script } ` an error is thrown when I call `\foo`, because `seccntformat` requires an argument.     Could somebody please tell me how to make the script into a macro?

Answer (score 0):

With KOMA you can use the `nonumber=true` option in your sections.

You just need to enable the optional arguments when choosing the *(KOMA)* class:

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}
```

Then you can use:

```
\section[nonumber=true]{Numberless section}
```

This will hide the section number from the section header and the table of contents entry alike. Subsection numbering etc. are left unmodified.

There's also `\addsec{Numberless section}` which does the same thing but isn't quite as generic.