# Include Subsection Number in Section Number

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I would like Sections to display the subsection number,
but I feel that redefining `\thesection` will recursively affect `\thesubsection`.

Basically, we're looking to add a zero to the section number in headings and the table of contents.

**Example**:

What we currently get:

```
1.  Section 1   
1.1 Section 1, Subsection 1  
1.2 Section 1, Subsection 2
```

What we're looking to get:

```
1.0 Section 1  
1.1 Section 1, Subsection 1  
1.2 Section 1, Subsection 2
```

**Additional info**:

This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80113/hide-section-numbers-but-keep-numbering) was a helpful start.

Comment: What is the use of this?

Comment: Our administrator wants this syntax for the documents we're sending out. We're at his mercy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply changing `\thesection` so that it would show whatever it is you want it after the number, then redefine `\thesubsection` so as not to call `\thesection`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \medskip
    text text
    \section{test}
    nah
    \subsection{test1}
    blah
    \subsection{test2}
    jah
\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image: just fixing the section]

If you wish to fix the TOC you can use the `tocloft` package thus

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}


\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\cftsecnumwidth{2.5em}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \medskip
    text text
    \section{test}
    nah
    \subsection{test1}
    blah
    \subsection{test2}
    jah
\end{document}
```

This would give you

[image: TOC fix added]

Comment: The indentations are off in the Table of Contents. Do you know any simple code to alleviate this? (Else I recommend checking [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-space-between-the-numbers-and-text-of-sectioning-titles-in-the) out.)  Either way, can you modify your answer to include a solution?

Comment: Much thanks.  All should note that the method proposed by egreg also works, (although it does not contain Elad Den's ToC fix at this time.)

Answer (score 2):

Redefine `\thesection` to refer to `subsection` and `\thesubsection` to be the same as `\thesection`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

\subsection{First subsection}

\subsection{Second subsection}

\section{Section}

\subsection{First subsection}

\subsection{Second subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Answer granted to @Elad Den for getting it in first.
Still, I appreciate your efforts equally. 
Leave a comment for a little rep : j

Comment: The indentations are off in the Table of Contents. Do you know any simple code to alleviate this? (Else I recommend checking [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33841/how-to-modify-the-space-between-the-numbers-and-text-of-sectioning-titles-in-the) out.)  Either way, can you modify your answer to include a solution?

Comment: @kando You could make sections the same as subsections: the zero will tell the reader which is which. Tell me if the idea is what you want.

Comment: Oop. I didn't see the subtle difference between you two. Does this fix the ToC? (A peer is making the edits. He used `\setlength{cftsecnumwidth}{+XXem}` from package `tocloft` to make his fix.)

Comment: @kando It's not clear whether you really want to repeat the section title in the subsection title.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your comment. I do not want to prepend the section label onto all of the subsection labels, if that is what you mean.  [Edit: I think you may believe this because of my example in my original question. I was merely being articulate by labeling each section number in text. I did not intend for these to signify actual textual headings. (I used 'code' format to get everything to line up via monospace font).]